# how to get the sum of a child column from another table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have a system that can get member information. i want my system to automatically get the name of the awardee. The conditions are if the member have recruited 6 people, he/she sold 15 soaps and his/her downlines sold 15 soaps each. Im using mysql and VB.NET so far i have this query.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    members m
LEFT JOIN
        geneology g
ON      SUM(m.status) >=90 AND
        m.upline = g.parent_id;
```

but i get

> 1111 error - invalid use of group function

Table 1 has columns

```
id, name, status 'This is where the soap data are stored', downlines, upline
```

Table 2 has columns

```
id, parent_id, child_id
```

Please help im new to sql queries

Comment: `SUM` is a group function but you haven't grouped by anything.

Comment: im grouping the m.status. is that wrong ^_^

Comment: Check Stefano's answer. You can see that there is a `group by` statement which then allows you to do a `sum`. The `having` is essentially a `where` but for grouped results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `ON` clause defines the criteria used to match the rows of the two tables, so that `SUM() >= 90` is not supposed to stay there (in fact, that's why you're getting that error).

I will assume that for a person on table `members`, `upline` is the `ID` of the member that recruited him/her. If that's correct, you can build your query like this:

```
select  t1.id, t1.name
from    members t1
join    geneology t2
on      t1.id = t2.parent_id
join    members t3
on      t2.child_id = t3.upline
where   t1.status = 15
group by t1.id, t1.name
having   count(distinct t3.id) = 6 and
         sum(t3.status) = 90
```

This will use the `members` table twice, once for the parent and once for the children, and the two tables are correlated by the `geneology` table.

The condition in the `where` clause is for the parent, then you group the child data for each parent, and only return the parents whose children satisfiy the conditions in the `having` clause.

Comment: Thanks so much bro. I had to edit some of the parts but the whole code is correct.